# Каким образом можно запустить Service без активити?

Tags: android

Хочу запустить Service без активити, тоесть без окон. Это не вирус, просто сервис для будильника, как бы дополнение.

AlarmManager слышал и делал, но суть там не много не в том что вы думаете. это дополнение для будильника которая в файле /data/data/package должна перезаписать файл.

Тоесть мое основное приложение с Activity, запустит apk дополнение. Вообщем это по сути не важно.
Можете все же подсказать можно ли в Android Studio сделать так чтобы запустить service без activity.

Тоесть в меню есть приложение. по нажатии на него, запуститься процесс, но его не будет видно, вот как то так. без root!.
читал про Broadcast Boot что - то там, попробовал не получилось...

Comment: Будильники иже с ними как мне кажется не болтаются постоянно в памяти где их может прибить android, вместо этого они используют AlarmManager, и android сам их запускает когда нужно.

Comment: `AlarmManager`, слышали про такое?

Comment: @nekaneka, дополнил вопрос.
metalurgus да знаю про него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/157-urok-92-service-prostoj-primer

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php

https://habrahabr.ru/post/265159/

http://programador.ru/sticky-service/

Гляньте, вдруг там то, что Вы ищите.